# enumerate a list and print every other element only

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, enumerate

I have

```
my_list = ['a','1','b','2','c','1','d','6']
```

I want to print:

```
>>letter: a number 1
  letter: b number 2
  letter: c number 1
  letter: d number 6
```

I've tried

```
for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
    print(f"letter {x} number {my_list[i+1]}")
```

but this prints

```
letter a number 1
letter 1 number b
letter b number 2
letter 2 number c
letter c number 1
letter 1 number d
letter d number 6
```

Seems I need to increment the x by 1 but how do I do that in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Do `zipping`

```
my_list = ['a','1','b','2','c','1','d','6']

for i,j in zip(my_list[::2],my_list[1::2]):
    print(f"letter {i} number {j}")
```

Output:

```
letter a number 1
letter b number 2
letter c number 1
letter d number 6
```

`enumerate` returns a counter with the element starting from 0. But looking from the output, you need to `zip()` alternate elements.

Comment: Ah I didn't understand the question in the beginning, now I edited my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code with `zip` and `'\n'.join`:

```
my_list = ['a','1','b','2','c','1','d','6']
print('\n'.join([f"letter {x} number {i}" for x, i in zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2])]))
```

Or try with `print` like this:

```
print(*[f"letter {x} number {i}" for x, i in zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2])], sep='\n')
```

Both codes output:

```
letter a number 1
letter b number 2
letter c number 1
letter d number 6
```

Answer (score 0):

No enumeration needed, as you have the numbers in your data already.  One concise way would zip an iterator with itself:

```
it = iter(my_list)
for x, y in zip(it, it):
    print(f"letter {x} number {y}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the `step` parameter of `range` function -

```
for i in range(0,len(my_list),2):
    print(f"letter {my_list[i]} number {my_list[i+1]}")
```

Result:

```
letter a number 1
letter b number 2
letter c number 1
letter d number 6
```